# Computer not responding to power changes after hardware upgrade

Tags: windows, boot, power

I upgraded my computers CPU/Mobo/RAM/GPU, and afterwards the power options are being strange.

- It won't fully shutdown, after Windows stops, and there's no video output, the computer wont actually stop
- It gets stuck on the blue "Restarting..." screen when trying to restart
- After going to sleep nothing will wake it back up, and I need to hard reset.

Ran a memory check and Windows found no issues with the RAM.

There was a boot partition issue after the upgrade (the Windows Boot Manager partition was set to hidden, which I fixed), so wondering if it could be something else related too?

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It's an issue with the OS, and since you changed the CPU and motherboard, a clean install is required - there's no way around that because the OS currently has the wrong drivers for the CPU and motherboard, with no way to uninstall them because they're installed as OEM drivers and are named as such [`oem###.inf`].  Windows isn't designed for hot-swapping components like that and requires you to run `SysPrep /Generalize` if wanting to do so since the PC is effectively a completely different machine with a different motherboard and CPU. Clean installing is preferable to SysPrep in this instance

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Once a motherboard or CPU has been swapped out for a different model, Windows must be [generalized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/generalize) via [SysPrep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation) _(doing so removes all OEM hardware drivers for installing the drive into a new machine)_. Once generalized, the next boot boots to Windows Setup's Pass 4: Generalize _(first link)_, then proceeds to OOBE, which is why clean installing is recommended in this instance.

Comment: I'll create an answer with the above info further fleshed out, but I don't have time at the moment